# Slow performance of DBASE IV on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a Win2008 Server that shares a folder which contains a set of DBASE IV files (DBFs and indexes). Those files are used by two different apps. The main one with read/write access and the second one read only.
We have 3 Win 7 machines and 1 XP machine.
The XP PC is not experiencing any slowdowns, while the Win 7 PCs cannot use the second app if any PC is using the first app, as the second app becomes so slow as to be unusable.

What I have already done: disabled oplocks in Win2008 Server, reviewed shares permissions, updated Win2008 with latest windows updates, set SMB1 on the client pc, disabled indexing on the shared folder unit, reviewed the server performance and found no hardware issues (disks are fast, the network is fast, I can't find any bottlenecks).
What else could be causing this problem? I don't know where to look next.
Why isn't the XP machine experiencing the same issues?
I'd like to know if someone else has had the same problem, or where to look next.
What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: DBASE IV? Are you kidding or are you a time traveller from the deep past? Consider flailing the server with dinosaur tails until the situation improves. Joking aside, are your applications actual DOS applications accessing these files or are they native Windows apps just using the DBF file format as a data backend?

Comment: No kidding. It's an accounting app, so backwards compatibility and ease of upgrade is very important. Not to talk about code maintainability. They are native windows app. The first one uses Borland Database Engine and it's surprisingly fast. The second one uses a DBASE ODBC and under the right settings is very fast. BTW, I normally work with relational DBs, but this is a third-party app...

Answer (score 0):

[I can't add comments yet, so a moderator can make this a comment if needed.]

Have you excluded the files from antivirus scanning on the server and the clients?  If you have three or four antivirus trying to scan the files all at the same time that would be ugly.  I know that doesn't explain why the XP machine is still doing OK, but it came to mind and it's relatively easy to try.

I would also recommend setting the network adapter drivers on the Windows 7 and server machines to disable speed/duplex auto-detect and set it to the highest speed your switch supports.  Also disable checksum offloading, receive side scaling, large send offload on all adapters as these lovely features often cause significant network issues.

Comment: See http://www.sysprobs.com/windows-7-network-slow for some more things to try.

Comment: The share is excluded from antivirus scan (all machines have the same AV and settings). I have modified the network adapter settings on the server side, and I am quite sure that's not where the problem lays. I am going to try the suggestions in the above link as soon as possible, hoping there's one setting on the client side that will solve the problem...

Comment: I agree--with the symptoms you've reported it looks to be a problem with the Windows 7 machines.  I have seen those settings I recommended disabling cause problems like this dozens of times, so I strongly suggest disabling them on at least one Windows 7 machine to see if it has any impact.  If all of the Windows 7 machines have the same adapter and driver, that makes these setting more suspicious.  Updating the NIC drivers may fix it, also.  I first got burned by speed/duplex auto-detect in 1996, and it is insane how badly this is implemented by various network device drivers and firmware.